# Like button that opens Facebook app

Tags: javascript, ios, facebook

I know it is not possible to directly like something through any Facebook API, but since I can create a like-button on my website that the user can click, is it possible to create a like button that likes a page through the iOS facebook App?

I know you can include the functionality to like using the facebook app if you are  developing iOS apps, but is it possible (using javascript?) to make a "like" button that  likes through the facebook app, instead of through the browser?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to force a like trough the facebook app, it still needs a second interaction of the user (a press on the like button).

A workaround would be to let the user like your page trough the webbrowser and after the like has been processed you redirect the user to the facebook app.

Read more about the events of a like button here:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Event.subscribe/v2.4

Comment: The problem is that people who visit my site are usually not logged in on facebook on their browsers - thus, if they want to like me they have to press the like button, and log on with their E-mail and password. However almost all of them have the facebook app, and I was hoping it was possible to do a "Like" link with a confirmation box in the facebook app